# How to properly declare links in extjs5 viewmodel?

Tags: javascript, extjs, mvvm, extjs5

This is how I define a ViewModel

```
Ext.define('CPCApplication.view.cases.ApplicationFormModel', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
alias: 'viewmodel.cases-applicationform',

links: {
    theForm: {
        type: 'CPCApplication.model.Test',
        create: true
    }
},
```

While this viewmodel is created I get an exception

```
[W] XTemplate evaluation exception: Invalid model name: CPCApplication.model.Test
```

Which actually means that it was not able to locate such a type in the default schema. But this type exists

```
Ext.define('CPCApplication.model.Test', {
    extend: 'CPCApplication.model.Base',
    fields: [
        { name: 'FisrtName', type: 'string' }

    ]
});
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
requires: ['CPCApplication.model.Test']
```

To your view model.